# Is it good practice to add new params to an API json request for API automation testing?

Tags: automated-tests, rest-assured

For Example: I have a POST API with json request as below

```
{
    "items":[
      {
        "name": "abc",
        "gender": "female",
        "companyName": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now, I would like to add a new field called comment to indicate what the json request is testing for? something like this

```
{
    "comment": "test employee with name",
    "items":[
      {
        "name": "abc",
        "gender": "female",
        "companyName": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it a good practice to add/modify params for testing purpose to a json request?
If not, what are the other ways to do this? 
I am using TestNG, RestAssured and JAVA to do API automation testing

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

This will not even work as the json schema for payload will be changed if you add another attribute. That will throw you an exception.

If you want to add description, you can add that to your tests. You can achieve this in testng by adding description attribute in the @Test annotation.

```
@Test(description = "This a new test", dependsOnMethods = "test1")
public void test2(){
     ...
}
```